# Call function inside a function?

Tags: sql, function, join

Let's say I have 3 tables;

the first one table_1 contains 3 columns :

- country
- date
- city
- key

and the other table table_2 contains columns :

- year
- value
- key

how can I write a function with two parameters (a,b) to return a table which is a join:

```
select * from table_1 where data =a
```

and:

```
select * from table_2 where year = b
```

Comment: Do you know how to join tables?

Comment: What parameters you're going to pass it must be a key column in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Select * from table_1
inner join table_2 on table_1.data = a and table_2.year = b
```